# How to run skactions randomly

Tags: spritekit, swift

Hey guys I need some help I have 2 SkActions.

```
ball1.run(SKAction.moveTo(y: -self.size.height * 0.2, duration: 1.5))
ball2.run(SKAction.moveTo(y: self.size.height * 1.2, duration: 1.5))
```

and I want to randomize which one gets called I dont want to run a sequence and no clue how to do it. I've tried a switch statement and an enum but that didn't work.

this is what I have tried. so essentially when I move my player to the right it could be attacked form the top or the bottom.

```
switch swipeGesture.direction {

case .right:
bat.run(SKAction.moveBy(x: 50, y:0, duration:0.01))
    ball1.run(SKAction.moveTo(y: -self.size.height * 0.2, duration: 
1.5)) || ball2.run(SKAction.moveTo(y: self.size.height * 1.2, duration: 1.5))

case .left:
bat.run(SKAction.moveBy(x: -50, y:0, duration:0.01))
       ball1.run(SKAction.moveTo(y: -self.size.height * 0.2, duration: 1.5)) || ball2.run(SKAction.moveTo(y: self.size.height * 1.2, duration: 1.5))
```

and it gives me an error: Cannot convert value of type 'Void' to expected argument type 'Bool'

If anybody know how to do so that would be great.

Comment: Can you show us how you've tried to apply a switch statement to this problem? Be sure to show the full context so we can see when the switch statement is executed.

Comment: @DMGregory sure I will update the post thanks.